# how to prevent escaping when using newlines in text interpolation (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

The following three lines of code:

```
array = ["line 2", "line 3"]
foo = array.join("\n")
bar = "line 1\n#{foo}\nline4"
```

result in

```
"line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline4"
```

is it possible to combine the 2nd and 3rd line using interpolation?  The following doesn't work:

```
bar = "line 1\n#{array.join('\n')}\nline4"
```

because it adds an extra backslash:

```
"line 1\nline 2\\nline 3\nline4"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes around `"\n"` if you want Ruby to treat it as a newline character instead of two separate characters:

```
bar = "line 1\n#{array.join("\n")}\nline4"
                            ^^^^
```